# How to get multi selected checked items (android)?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I followed this tutorial chapter 14, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection but I am trying to figure out how to implement my submit button to grab the checked items...

This was my attempt but apparently the checked items return as false in my submit button, not sure what is going on exactly and looking through google and SO I only found answers to having a regular adapter.

Here is the code:

```
public class RegisterFollowup extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
Button btnCategoriesSubmit;
ListView categoriesList;

//adapter with custom model
ArrayAdapter<MultiSelectItem> adapter;

//list with custom model
List<MultiSelectItem> list;

ArrayList<MultiSelectItem> selected;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_followup);

    //setup portrait mode for app
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //button categories submit
    btnCategoriesSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCategoriesSubmit);
    btnCategoriesSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Set adapter for multi-select model and adapter
    adapter = new MultiSelectAdapter(this, getMultiSelectItem());
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //get the list view and set it in activity to a listview
    //categoriesList = getListView();

    //setChoicemode
    //getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    selected = new ArrayList<MultiSelectItem>();

}

//call to retrieve list
private List<MultiSelectItem> getMultiSelectItem() {
    //initiate new list
    list = new ArrayList<MultiSelectItem>();

    //called to get string array
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] categories = res.getStringArray(R.array.categories);

    //loop through string array
    for(String category: categories) {
        Log.e("cat", "categ: " + category);
        list.add(get(category));
    }
    return list;
}

//call model to set names and methods for each item
private MultiSelectItem get(String s) {
    return new MultiSelectItem(s);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == btnCategoriesSubmit) {
        Log.e("string results", "string results " + getMultiSelectItem().size());
        for(int i=0;i< getMultiSelectItem().size();i++){
            MultiSelectItem item = getMultiSelectItem().get(i);
            if(item.isSelected()){
                selected.add(item);
            }
        }

        Log.e("string results", "string results selected " + selected.size());
       }
      } 
    }
```

Here is my code for the adapter:

```
public class MultiSelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MultiSelectItem> {

private final List<MultiSelectItem> list;
private final Activity context;


public MultiSelectAdapter(Activity context, List<MultiSelectItem> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.multi_select_layout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_select_layout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        MultiSelectItem element = (MultiSelectItem) viewHolder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    return view;
}
}
```

Here is the model:

```
public class MultiSelectItem {
private String name;
private boolean selected;

public MultiSelectItem(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    selected = false;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
}
```

Comment: first, why are you setting the choice mode only after clicking submit button? I believe, you should set it right before allowing the user to  select items.

Comment: Ok, even if I moved the placement of it, it still gives me the same results where in the submit button it shows up as false even when items are clearly selected...

Comment: follow this tutorial, may help you http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-create-multi-select-listview-android-with-custom-adapter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making these edits to the code:

Added this to the end of the adapter as 3 more methods

```
public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public MultiSelectItem getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Then added this to my activity: (in the button)

```
List<MultiSelectItem> checkedData = adapter.list;
            Log.e("string results", "string results " + getMultiSelectItem().size());
            for(MultiSelectItem item :checkedData) {
                if(item.isSelected()) {
                    Log.e("checker", item.getName());
                }
            }
```

and this minor change to the adapter on top:

```
//adapter with custom model
    private MultiSelectAdapter adapter;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<MultiSelectedItem> selected = new ArrayList<MultiSelectedItem>();


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == btnCategoriesSubmit) {
       for(int i=0;i< getMultiSelectItem().size;i++){
           MultiSelectItem item = getMultiSelectItem().get(i);
           if(item.isSelected()){
               selected.add(item);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

does that make any sence to you ? :)

EDIT:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.multi_select_layou, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    MultiSelectItem element = (MultiSelectItem) cb.getTag();
                    element .setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(list.get(position));
        return convertView ;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but I am getting an error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4  and it is referring to this line MultiSelectItem item = getMultiSelectItem().get(i);  and I am assuming I should get rid of this line getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); right?

Comment: yes you do ... you already have the button defined in your own adapter for listview ...

Comment: I still get 0 items selected as the result and by the way I know it is .size(), which I already changed so that is not a problem either it returns the correct size, and goes through the loop but it is as if it does not return any selected items

Comment: Thanks for helping me by the way, I really appreciate it, but yeah still getting 0 back, I am going to edit above the code for the main activity file so you can see my implementation

Comment: Thats strange ... its working for me :X still returns zero ? :)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to not be pulling it correctly in the activity file, as nothing is getting added

Comment: I think the code for the adapter has to be retrieved somehow, since we are just hitting the model from the activity file